# Criteria for getting month from date in hibernate3

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have stored the date in my database (not months).i want to get the records from particular month.Is it possible to write criteria for this in hibernate3?

Comment: can you give more information please.

Comment: please check if this is want you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233900/how-to-dynamically-search-between-two-dates-in-hql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this

Date startDate = 2014-03-01

Date endDate = 2014-03-31

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getDomainClass());
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("date", startDate, endDate));

**(OR)**

If your date format is "YYYY-MM-DD"

String date = "2014-03";

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getDomainClass());

criteria.add(Restrictions.like("date", date));