# hql query to select values within some date

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g

i came into a situation where i want to select rows which meets within some date.

i am using oracle and my query looks like :-

**Query**

```
SELECT d.id,d.ADVERTISEMENTCODE,d.LASTDATEOFFORMSUBMISSION,e.LASTDATEFORFORMSUBMISSION,
d.studentMasterId FROM CANDIDATEAPPEARAGAINSTADVTCODE d LEFT OUTER JOIN ADVERTISEMENTCODE e
   ON d.ADVERTISEMENTCODE = e.ADVERTISEMENTCODE WHERE paymentStatus='Pending' 
and studentMasterId='8670' and 
TO_DATE(e.LASTDATEFORFORMSUBMISSION,'dd/mm/yyyy')+4 > TO_DATE('11/05/2017','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

this is a running query and it returns exactly what i want.
[image]

but now i want to do it with hibernate query language. how can it be done?

Comment: does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277135/3959856

Comment: and this one is in hql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233900/how-to-dynamically-search-between-two-dates-in-hql/17359713#17359713